# Why is the output always the same?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, module, cube

My task is to check whether or not a number's (maximum eight digits) individual digits cubed will equal the number inputted (has to remain as a string). For example, 215 would return 2 x 2 x 2 + 1 x 1 x 1 + 5 x 5 x 5 = 134 (not true).

- 371 = 3 x 3 x 3 + 7 x 7 x 7 + 1 x 1 x 1 = 371 (true)

The program is to continue forever until an input of 0 is made. I understand that I have to make a function before the main program. But my program never breaks even if I enter 0...

```
def sum_of_cubes(num):
    num_string = str(num)
    sum = 0
    for i in  num_string:
        digit = int(i)
        cube = digit * digit * digit
        sum = sum + cube
        return sum

def main():
     while True:
        number = input("Enter a number (max 8 digits): ")
        result = sum_of_cubes(number)
        print(result)
        number_result= str(result)

    if result == number:
        print("Yes")

    if result!= number:
        print("No")

    if number=='0':
        break
```

main()

Comment: Youre cubing each digit, and then only adding the last iteration/ final digit cubed to a sum of 0 and returning it. You need to add to the sum _in_ your loop

Comment: Please *don't* change the code in your question in reaction to comments or answers. This renders them irrelevant and makes your question a moving target. This is not how SO is supposed to work...

Answer (score 0):

You should add the cubed numbers to the sum inside the for loop.
you currently have it outside, so it will add only the last digit's cubed number.
try this:

.
.
.

```
sum = 0
for i in  num_string:
        digit = int(i)
        cube = digit * digit * digit
        sum = sum + cube
return sum
```

Comment: if I type in 215 using this it returns the number 8 instead of 134

Comment: Very strange. Plz double check indentation in your `sum_of_cubes()` function.

Comment: I updated the code in the question. that's what it looks like

Comment: you should put the `return sum` outside the for loop

Comment: Now it's working. thank you! but the if statements to check if the digits are equal to the number always output No. Do you know a way I can fix this?

Comment: I think it's because restult is an int while number is a sting, try casting one of them..